# How to print parser tree in Yacc (BISON)

Tags: parsing, bison, yacc

I made a parser for the C- language using BISON and FlEX. It works and prints "syntax error" in terminal if given c- input code is syntactically wrong, otherwise print nothing.

But i want to **print the parser tree** relevant to given c- input code as the output of my parser. How do i do that? Is there function in BISON which can be used to print the parser tree?

Comment: Do you mean you want to print the AST for an expression you parse? If so, you'll need to implement that yourself -- I'm reasonably certain neither yacc nor Bison has anything to do it for you.

Answer (score 1):

The TXR language (http://www.nongnu.org/txr) uses Flex and Yacc for parsing its input. You can see the parse tree if you give it the `-v` option.

E.g.:

```
$ ./txr -v -c "@/[a-z]*|foo/"
spec:
(((text (#<sys:regex: 9d99268> or (0+ (set (#\a . #\z))) (compound #\f #\o #\o)))))
```

You construct the tree in the parser actions and print it yourself with a tree-printing routine. I used a Lisp-like object representation to make life easier.
Writing this out is handled by a recursive printing function which recognizes all the possible object types and renders them into notation. For instance above you see objects of character type printed with a hash-backslash notation, and the unprintable, opaque, compiled regex is printed using the notation `#< ... >`.

Here is a part of the grammar:

```
regexpr : regbranch                     { $$ = if3(cdr($1), 
                                                   cons(compound_s, $1),
                                                   car($1)); }
        | regexpr '|' regexpr           { $$ = list(or_s, $1, $3, nao); }
        | regexpr '&' regexpr           { $$ = list(and_s, $1, $3, nao); }
        | '~' regexpr                   { $$ = list(compl_s, $2, nao); }
        | /* empty */ %prec LOW         { $$ = nil; }
        ;
```

As you can see, constructing the AST is largely just simple construction of nested lists.
This form is very convenient to compile. The top-level function of the NFA-based regex compiler is very readable:

```
/*
 * Input is the items from a regex form,
 * not including the regex symbol.
 * I.e.  (rest '(regex ...)) not '(regex ...).
 */
static nfa_t nfa_compile_regex(val exp)
{
  if (nullp(exp)) {
    nfa_state_t *acc = nfa_state_accept();
    nfa_state_t *s = nfa_state_empty(acc, 0);
    return nfa_make(s, acc);
  } else if (typeof(exp) == chr_s) {
    nfa_state_t *acc = nfa_state_accept();
    nfa_state_t *s = nfa_state_single(acc, c_chr(exp));
    return nfa_make(s, acc);
  } else if (exp == wild_s) {
    nfa_state_t *acc = nfa_state_accept();
    nfa_state_t *s = nfa_state_wild(acc);
    return nfa_make(s, acc);
  } else {
    val sym = first(exp), args = rest(exp);

    if (sym == set_s) {
      return nfa_compile_set(args, nil);
    } else if (sym == cset_s) {
      return nfa_compile_set(args, t);
    } else if (sym == compound_s) {
      return nfa_compile_list(args);
    } else if (sym == zeroplus_s) {
      nfa_t nfa_arg = nfa_compile_regex(first(args));
      nfa_state_t *acc = nfa_state_accept();
      /* New start state has empty transitions going through
         the inner NFA, or skipping it right to the new acceptance state. */
      nfa_state_t *s = nfa_state_empty(nfa_arg.start, acc);
      /* Convert acceptance state of inner NFA to one which has
         an empty transition back to the start state, and
         an empty transition to the new acceptance state. */
      nfa_state_empty_convert(nfa_arg.accept, nfa_arg.start, acc);
      return nfa_make(s, acc);
    } else if (sym == oneplus_s) {
      /* One-plus case differs from zero-plus in that the new start state
         does not have an empty transition to the acceptance state.
         So the inner NFA must be traversed once. */
      nfa_t nfa_arg = nfa_compile_regex(first(args));
      nfa_state_t *acc = nfa_state_accept();
      nfa_state_t *s = nfa_state_empty(nfa_arg.start, 0); /* <-- diff */
      nfa_state_empty_convert(nfa_arg.accept, nfa_arg.start, acc);
      return nfa_make(s, acc);
    } else if (sym == optional_s) {
      /* In this case, we can keep the acceptance state of the inner
         NFA as the acceptance state of the new NFA. We simply add
         a new start state which can short-circuit to it via an empty
         transition.  */
      nfa_t nfa_arg = nfa_compile_regex(first(args));
      nfa_state_t *s = nfa_state_empty(nfa_arg.start, nfa_arg.accept);
      return nfa_make(s, nfa_arg.accept);
    } else if (sym == or_s) {
      /* Simple: make a new start and acceptance state, which form
         the ends of a spindle that goes through two branches. */
      nfa_t nfa_first = nfa_compile_regex(first(args));
      nfa_t nfa_second = nfa_compile_regex(second(args));
      nfa_state_t *acc = nfa_state_accept();
      /* New state s has empty transitions into each inner NFA. */
      nfa_state_t *s = nfa_state_empty(nfa_first.start, nfa_second.start);
      /* Acceptance state of each inner NFA converted to empty
         transition to new combined acceptance state. */
      nfa_state_empty_convert(nfa_first.accept, acc, 0);
      nfa_state_empty_convert(nfa_second.accept, acc, 0);
      return nfa_make(s, acc);
    } else {
      internal_error("bad operator in regex");
    }
  }
}
```